# Which C specifiers may cause ABI incompatibility between the caller and callee?

Tags: c, abi, qualifiers, storage-class-specifier

Suppose there is a file with a declaration of a function which differs from the actual definition in another file i.e.

FileA.c

```
short foo();

int main(){
   foo();
}
```

FileB.c

```
int foo(){
   //Some code
}
```

This is obviously wrong code but it illustrates what the topic is.

The problem is that a compiler will not produce a machine code that will reserve enough space for the return value of `foo` when it's called. I think this can be called ABI incompatibility.

There are multiple different specifiers one may apply to a function or variable i.e. type qualifiers, storage class specifiers, atomics etc. I wonder which of these could potentially cause any kind of incompatibilities between a caller and a callee. Consider the case that these files might be compiled to separate binaries but still call the function via a pointer to an address.

Comment: The compiler isn't reserving any space for the return value because the caller ignores it. Anyway, the `short` or `int` value returned will typically be in a register, not in memory. But if the linker fails to notice the conflict and produces an executable then you have *undefined behaviour*. This is why the prototype for `foo` **should be in a header file** `FileB.h`.

Comment: Yeah the code you posted isn't "obviously wrong".  It will be wrong on some architectures but on x86_64, the return value goes in a register and the mismatch doesn't matter.  You can trivially see this using Compiler Explorer:  https://godbolt.org/z/3zGTvrEcW   In the end, the answer to your question is just "it depends on your architecture and calling convention" and you have to really know what you're doing if you want the signatures to be different.  It's probably safe on most systems to replace a pointer type with another pointer type, and integers with integers of the same size.

Comment: @DavidGrayson It's not UB if the type declaration in the caller is different from the definition?

Comment: This question is not about undefined behavior.

Comment: While in this specific case the values can easily go into a register it can happen that the types are too big or there are too many parameters. 
I don't want to declare different signatures on purpose. I have a situation where I have to implement a jump table for a library in a bare-metal application. For this I need to translate header files of a library to extern storage-class. I am trying to find out what can be relevant to keep and that can be ignored when I create a new header file programmatically.

Comment: The example isn't using a header file.

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes because it doesn't matter if the declaration is in a header file or not. I was trying to create a general question, not one specific to my problem.

Comment: You probably need to study the C standard on the topic of [§6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.7).  It tells you what the standard guarantees (or requires).  The best way to deal with declarations of extern declarations between translation units (TU) is to use the same header in both TUs.  This is what allows you to use, for example, the functions from `<stdio.h>` in multiple TUs.  The alternatives are tricky to handle reliably.  Declarations don't cost anything at runtime — even in memory-constrained systems, include the correct information.

Comment: @patvax is does matter, because the compiler can pick up the error.

Comment: @WeatherVane Not if both files are linked into separate binaries.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler wrote that the should both use the same header. Are you trying to link to a binary that you don't have an interface for (ie guessing)?

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes this would give a guarantee that it is all correct, but this makes it harder to provide one binary with the address of the function in another library.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you I will look into it and maybe I can find the answers that I am looking for.

Comment: @WeatherVane Since you asked:
I am in a bare-metal environment. I am developing a bootloader which needs the same library as the application. My idea was to share the library between both. I am adding a jump table to the library binary and access the symbols from the bootloader via this table(This approach requires the header with extern specifiers. If there is another way I haven't found it yet). Binding the application to the addresses from the library is then trivial. Unfortunately I only have the library in a compiled form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder which of these could potentially cause any kind of incompatibilities between a caller and a callee"

Simply assume **any difference** risks incompatibility.

Some difference are OK, yet those are often implementation defined.  There is little value in exploiting a difference that is compatibility.

See also [direct qualifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145292/which-c-specifiers-may-cause-abi-incompatibility-between-the-caller-and-callee/77145894?noredirect=1#comment136001337_77145894).

[The best way to deal with declarations of extern declarations between translation units (TU) is to use the same header in both TUs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77145292/which-c-specifiers-may-cause-abi-incompatibility-between-the-caller-and-callee/77145894#comment135999484_77145292)

Comment: A difference in direct qualifiers is okay and cannot cause incompatibility because they are stripped from function return types, per C 2018 6.7.6.3 5.